# Programmatically change volume of Rdio RDPlayer?

Tags: ios, rdio

I'm using Rdio's iOS API in my project and would like to change the volume at which the RDPlayer plays music. Is there a way to do this? I see in their documentation that you can do this on the web API, but I haven't found any information on their iOS API.

Answer (score 0):

The Rdio iOS SDK doesn't support volume controls.